# Wiring for smart ceiling fan with AC adapter

Tags: electrical

I have a Carro smart ceiling fan with a light and remote with two wall switches. The wiring from the ceiling is red, black, white and ground; there is an AC adapter pack plug in from the fan as well as a black and white wire only.

Where does the red wire from the ceiling go on the wires to the fan?

Can I put the red, and black from the celing together on the black from the fan? Or red from the celing on the black from the fan and cap the black from the celing?

Comment: What did the two switches control before?

Comment: It’s a fairly new build and They were never connected. The celing plate was still on with no previous fixture

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the wiring diagram that came with the instructions?

Comment: Yes, can you provide us with the model # of this ceiling fan please?

Comment: It sounds like you only need 1 hot so you can cap the other. It is very common to use x3 so you can have 2 switches since you only need 1 cap the other.